# Reset input value for Android>Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have an issue on **Firefox** for **Android**, i have a `<textarea>` where i need to  write the textarea value into a `<div>` and reset it value on `keyUp`.
It works well on Chrome for android but in firefox the value is never reset.

HTML :

```
<textarea id="area" autocapitalize='none'></textarea>
<div id="res"></div>
```

JS :

```
$('#area').on('keyup', function(e){
    $('#res').html($('#res').html() + this.value);
    $(this).val("");
    $(this).text("");
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j11LL5r8/6/)

Eg. In Chrome for Android, when i type "lol", the `div` will contains "lol".
In Firefox for Android, the `div` will contains "llolol"....

Any idea ? :)

**PS:** the code need to be tested on Firefox for Android.

**UPDATE:** May be a start of anwser :

When i `blur` the `<textarea>` after typing a key on virtual keyboard, the value is reseted... but not if i dont lose the `focus`.

The issue is the same if a change `<textarea>` by `<input type="text">`.

Comment: `$(this)text("");` does not refer to `div` element. Use `$('#res').html('')` to clear the div content....Not sure what is the purpose of your code..As it will always clear the content of the DIV and textarea..

Comment: @RayonDabre I don't want to clear the `div` but the `textarea`. Each time i type a letter in the `textarea` i need to append this letter in the `div` and clear the `textarea`

Comment: Then what is the purpose of `$(this).text("");` ?

Comment: Just a security to prevent `$("#area").text("something");` somewhere in code

Comment: try the `input` event. I am not sure what exactly is the issue.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Thx for reply, i have tried to change `keyup` by `input` but the issue is the same :(